# alarm broadcastreceiver sometimes not called on exact time or getting intents multiple times

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I try to make AlarmManager to broadcast pending intent using setRepeating function.

Here's registering broadcaster receiver and set repeating alarm in same place. This is not onResume, but other class' function.

```
    IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(DATATIMER_ACTION_ALARM_REPEAT) ;
    alarmReceiver=new AlarmReceiver() ;
    AttachedContext.registerReceiver(alarmReceiver,filter) ;


    intent=new Intent(DATATIMER_ACTION_ALARM_REPEAT) ;
    pIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AttachedContext,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) ;
    alarmManager=(AlarmManager)AttachedContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) ;
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,0,minimumRequiredPeriod,pIntent) ;
```

Currently in     setRepeating    function, minimumRequiredPeriod is 2000 so i wanted alarm to be repeatedly triggered at every 2 second. And i set RTC_WAKEUP mode to wake device up to do something. And i started app, and it showed correct result as i expected like log below:

```
09-01 20:29:10.002  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:29:12.002  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:29:14.002  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:29:16.002  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:29:18.002  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
```

But few minutes after i turned the screen off, it started to print wrong log and keeps doing that, which says that alarm intent is not called at interval i set before and i also get multiple intents at one time unit like below:

```
09-01 20:32:07.672  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:32:07.722  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:32:07.732  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:32:07.757  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
09-01 20:32:08.002  11447-11447/? I/DataTimer alarm﹕ alarmReceived
```

The code below is my receiver class.

```
private class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        wakelock.acquire() ;

        if(intent.getAction().equals(DATATIMER_ACTION_ALARM_REPEAT)) {

            Log.i("DataTimer alarm", "alarmReceived") ;

     for (int i = 0; i < dataTimerListenerPeriodList.size(); i++) {

  if (dataTimerListenerPeriodList.get(i) == dataTimerListenerPeriodCheckList[i]) {
                    dataTimerListenerList.get(i).onEveryElapseEvent();
                    dataTimerListenerPeriodCheckList[i] = 1;
                } else
                    dataTimerListenerPeriodCheckList[i]++;

            }

        }

        wakelock.release() ;

    }
}
```

I also used WakefulBroadcastReceiver to receive alarm intent and to keep device on but didn't work too, so i changed back to the code above. Can someone help me why i get alarm intent at wrong time or getting multiple intents at one time after i pressed turn off button.

Thanks for reply from @ci_, i used timer and did both 2 second, 1 minute inside timer thread. First seemed it was working with almost exact interval, but i found that it was working because it was connected to computer. After i unplugged my phone, and timer started to print log very slowly, like 1 per 6 minute interval. So i think timer isnt working too when device's screen turned off.

I  saw [post](http://code4reference.com/2012/07/android-homescreen-widget-with-alarmmanager/) that uses alarm manager with 1 second interval. I also think alarm manager is not the problem becasue on the log at wrong interval above, it seems that those intents are already fired at correct interval 'previously' , but broadcast receiver sometimes doesnt get those intents at the same time intents are fired by alarm manager when screen goes off. It was same when i used WakefulBroadcastService. Hmm, im curious how apps like sleep tracking, like Sleep as android, works when screen is off and doesnt consume that much of battery. Can someone suggest me some work around on why broadcast receiver doesnt get intents at the same time those are fired?

Comment: `AlarmManager` isn't intended for short timing operations, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html use a 'Handler' instead.

Comment: @ci_ I read that phrase before but what i need here is to be able to do repetitive thing at fixed interval which i can cinfigure, and working even after device screen is off. The first approach i took was to use timer with wakelock so that it prevents cpu from sleep.But when i acquired wakelock and didnt release for some time, my device was too hot, so i had to find out something more efficient so i searcher web and found this method. But like i said above and seeing comment, i need to find other way that is efficient in battery usage, and doesnt stop when device's screen is turned off

Comment: Having a task repeat every 2 seconds is not efficient in terms of battery usage, no matter what you do, the device will never be able to enter sleep mode. Otherwise `AlarmManager` is _the_ way to go, just not every 2 seconds.

Comment: @ci_ Oh, i didn't know that phone doesn't go to sleep even screen is off if there's timer that does work at relatively fast speed...!! It is now working fine now. Reason i needed 2 second interval was that i needed to calculate something every 2 second. Hmm...can i ask you one more?  i have onother task that has to run at every 1minute, so if i also put this task in timer, would device wouldn't go to sleep too? or i have to use alarmManager to do this?

Comment: The device will eventually go into sleep mode, unless you use wake locks. The `AlarmManager` is able to schedule alarms that wake up the device. If it works reliable with 1 minute intervals is something you might have to try yourself. But either way, doing work every minute means the device will have to wake up every minute, you have to see for yourself if the battery drain is acceptable to you or not.

Comment: @ci_ You really saved my time. I'm using both 2second, 1 minute tasks in timer and seems it doesn't go to sleep mode. Actually, i was making sleep tracking app so i needed device to be awake anyway. Also device isn't as hot as getting wake-lock for so long time. Thank you!!